# Magento2.4: Which files are used to render this advance inventory pop up?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, catalog, catalogsearch

I want to find out which files are used to render This advance inventory pop up from the catalog product edit option? and stock status option where are those values coming from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This form is defined in the `vendor/magento/module-catalog-inventory/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`

Data Source for it is defined in the `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml`:

```
<dataSource name="product_form_data_source">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataProvider class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider" name="product_form_data_source">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
            <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>
```

so data comes from the `Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\ProductDataProvider` class.